# contextual action mode hiding when device screen off

Tags: android

In my application i have  contextual action mode when it is open if I click on device lock button and unlock at time action mode is hiding. after unlock also i need to display same as before  lock. When I click on device lock button at that time it is calling onDestroyActionMode. how to stop this one. or any solution to show actionmode.